# How can I make KDB sleep for 5 seconds?

Tags: kdb

I've got a rate-limited endpoint I'm querying, and so I need to make KDB pause between requests. Is there a way I can block the current thread?

Comment: How are these requests arriving? Are you pulling them from a queue that's coming in, or are users sending the request directly to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions using `system` are good for the majority of use cases. If you want an OS-agnostic method, the below lambda can be used, passing the time to wait as an argument:

```
{t:.z.p;while[.z.p<t+x]} 00:00:05
```

This approach can also be used if you're making these requests using secondary/slave threads (for example, using `peach`), whereas attempting to use the `system` keyword will fail in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
system"sleep 5"
```

on linux OS

Answer (score 1):

```
system"timeout 5"
```

on Windows OS

For reference `system` lets you run any commands native to the OS. Like doing `\` in the terminal e.g. `\timeout 5` ~ `system"timeout 5"`